# WPF Button Command not firing ICommand in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, modern-ui

I have a View with a button as follows:

```
<Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Content="Test" Margin="10,4" 
        Command="{Binding DataContext.CmdTestButtonClicked}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
```

In the view's code-behind, I set the DataContext to the ViewModel:

```
public GlobalSettings()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ...

    DataContext = Helpers.IoCHelper.GlobalSettingsVM;

    ...
}
```

My ViewModel derives from a base class which exposes the `ICommand`:

```
public class GlobalSettingsVM : CollectionViewModel<GlobalSettings> { ... }

public abstract class CollectionViewModel<TModel> : IInstallModuleViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged,
        INotifyDataErrorInfo where TModel : Model, new()
{
    ...

    public ICommand CmdTestButtonClicked
    {
        get
        {
            return _testButtonClicked ??
                   (_testButtonClicked = new RelayCommand(TestButtonClicked));
        }
    }

    protected virtual void TestButtonClicked(object o)
    {
        // I never get here
    }
}
```

I don't have any other issues using this pattern throughout my application, however all my other implementations have the `Button` within a `ListView`, so there I have to use `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}`.

Why would this command never fire? Do I need to set a `RelativeSource` here as well?

Comment: I would try changing the `Command` on the `Button` to `{Binding Path=CmdTestButtonClicked}` otherwise you are attempting access the `DataContext` of the button which has not been set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.CmdTestButtonClicked}"
```

Implies that the Command will look for a property called `DataContext` in the object to which the button is bound. 
If the DataContext of the button is a `GlobalSettingsVM` this should work:

```
Command="{Binding CmdTestButtonClicked}"
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. I assumed the Button would just inherit the DataContext of its parent. I use the DataContext prefix elsewhere throughout my application without explicitly setting a control's DataContext and it works. Perhaps it's because I also set RelativeSource on those?

Comment: @MarkRichman, Indeed every control inherits the DataContext of its container. And yes, when you use RelativeSource youe are refering to a property of the control itself, not of the bound viewmodel.

Comment: And as a piece of advice, if you use RelativeSource to reference a DataContext you are (usually) doing something wrong or it's symptom of poor design.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the MVVM Light toolkit wich is very convenient and helping on these situations.

You would get Something like this :

```
<Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Content="Test" Margin="10,4" 
     <i:Interaction.Triggers>
           <i:EventTrigger EventName="OnClick" >
                 <Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.CmdTestButtonClicked}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
      </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: How is this simpler or better?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was listening to `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown`  under constructor of `xaml.cs` class which was stopping `command event callback` to the `view model`.

```
 this.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += (s, e) => DragMove();
```

Instead of above line, in xaml file for `window` added `MouseLeftButtonDown="Window_MouseLeftButtonDown"` click handler and handled window drag within it, as below

```
private void Window_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DragMove();
}
```